# Detect Application Quit with Unity?

Tags: windows, unity-game-engine, exit-code

I'm trying to use `System.AppDomain.CurentDomain.ApplicationExit += new System.EventHandler(SomeFunction);` to call the function `SomeFunction` when the application closes. In this case Unity 3D. But it doesn't work. I have no idea why. It is an editor script and is not an instance (static). What do you think I'm doing wrong?

Comment: what is your requirement of doing so?

Answer (score 1):

There is no `OnApplicationQuit` method for Windows. According to the official documentation:

> On Windows Store Apps and Windows Phone 8.1 there is no application quit event. Consider using OnApplicationFocus event when focusStatus equals false.

Therefore, instead of checking whether or not the application closed, you'll want to check whether or not the application obtained or lost focus.

In C#:

```
void OnApplicationFocus(bool focus)
{
    if (!focus)
    {
        //Do something
    }
}
```

The documentation does not explicitly mention it, but it can be assumed `OnApplicationQuit` is intended for Android only as iOS also does not support it.

Answer (score 0):

You could use

```
function OnApplicationQuit() {

//put script in here

}
```

So that before the application quits it calls that function and does what ever is in the { and }

Comment: This is simply wrong. For Windows Store Apps, the callback is not called. This stays right on the documentation page!